# Cannot install R package AICcmodavg

Tags: r

I am trying to install the R packages : AICcmodavg

```
> install.packages("AICcmodavg", lib="/my/own/R-packages/")
Avis : impossible d'accéder à l'index de l'entrepôt http://cran.cict.fr/src/contrib
Avis : impossible d'accéder à l'index de l'entrepôt http://cran.cict.fr/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15
Message d'avis :
package ‘AICcmodavg’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

Does it mean that I have to change R version, I have to install a less recent version than the R version 2.15.2 ? Or what can I do ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Try to install the newest version of R.

Comment: That, and change your CRAN mirror, because yours is not accessible.

Answer (score 2):

You need a *more* recent version of `R` not a less recent one.

[AICcmodavg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AICcmodavg/index.html) was written in Sept, 2013 and seems to require the latest `R`.

I tried

```
install.packages("AICcmodavg")
library(AICcmodavg)
```

and it worked fine with `R` 3.0.1